# SELECT AVG("...") with Criteria API

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hibernate, activerecord, criteria

I'm having difficulties with translating following SQL syntax into Criteria API:

```
SELECT AVG(dbo.Member.Points) FROM dbo.Member WHERE dbo.Member.PaidMemberRegDate IS NOT NULL;
```

I have a *Member* class with a *Points* property. I just want to get the average *Points* of all Members that have the property *PaidMemberRegDate* set to null.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use Projections to take care of this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(dbo.Member.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.avg("Points"))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotnUll("PaidMemberRegDate"))
```

Change the values around to match your class and associations and that should do it.